# Why does a 2-colourable simple graph with n nodes have no more than $(n^2/4)$ arcs?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, discrete-geometry

Why does a 2-colourable simple graph with n nodes have no more than $(n^2/4)$ arcs?

I would really appreciate for any kind of explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By 2-colorable graph I think is meant a coloring of nodes, so that any edge is between nodes of different colors, i.e. [a bipartite graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph).  Consider how to partition the $n$ nodes so that the number of edges by connecting all possible pairs will be largest.

Roughly we divide the nodes into two equal groups.  In the simplest case $n$ is even and we get $n/2$ in each part.  The most edges possible would be exactly the figure $(n/2)^2$ that appears in your question.

---

Let's work out how to maximize edges that cross from one part to the other (of a bipartite graph).  In total we have $n$ nodes.  Suppose we put $x$ nodes in one part and $n-x$ in the other, then make all the possible $x(n-x)$ edges between them.

What value of $x$ will maximize $x(n-x)$?  First we check the boundary conditions, i.e. if $x=0$ or equivalently $x=n$, then we get no edges (one of the two parts is empty).

So consider the intermediate values $0 \lt x \lt n$ and extend the counting to a continuous function of $x$ on the open interval $(0,n)$, i.e. $f(x) = x(n-x) = nx - x^2$.  Calculus tells us the maximum occurs at the critical point, $f'(n/2) = 0$, of this parabola.  Note that $f(n/2) = (n/2)^2$.

This is then an upper bound on the number of edges in a bipartite graph with $n$ nodes, but it can only be attained when $n$ is even.  If $n$ is odd, we can't quite split the nodes in two equal parts, and the best we can do is split them $\frac{n-1}{2}$ and $\frac{n+1}{2}$.

However we were only asked to show that $n^2/4$ is an upper bound (no more than this many edges or arcs), not to give the details of when the upper bound is *sharp* (can be met exactly).

Comment: the first part is much easier to understand than the proof i have in the given solution. but for the second part "The most edges possible would then be exactly the figure (n/2)^2". why is it squared?

Comment: Suppose *every* node in one part is connected to *every* node in the other part.  This is the most possible edges.  The maximum occurs when you split the nodes up equally into (say) $n/2$ nodes in each part.  It's an easy calculus exercise to show that splitting the nodes into two "as equal as possible" parts gives the most edges.  I'll add this to my answer if you like.